# Convert Photoshop animation to spritesheet

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, sprite

I have an animation that I have exported to gif, works perfect and all, but it is for a game and therefore I need to create a spritesheet for display. Also, I may be creating other animations for the spritesheet, the current animation is a character running maybe adding jumping, etc.

First off, is there an easy way to export an animation to a spritesheet? Secondly, what about adding other animations, I can do the cut and paste manually but is there an easier way?

Comment: Photoshop is scriptable using javascript, vbscript, and/or applscript, so if you are familiar with programming you might be able to put together your own. For intance: do what alan G suggests to create layers, and then iterate through the layers, copying each in turn, changing canvas size of secondary document as needed, and pasting/positioning the sprite layer.

Comment: you also might be able to manipulate the built-in contact sheet script(s) to take a folder of images and create the sprite sheet.

Comment: Not built-in any more, sadly. I think they disappeared in CS4. I couldn't think of anything in the Output module that would be useful for this purpose. Scripting would be the cool way to go, I'm guessing.

Comment: I'll give the scripting a shot, I'm using CS3 so it should be possible?

Answer (score 2):

Realize this post is old, but it had half of what I needed. To anyone that runs across this, another good tool is TexturePacker - http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker
Its pretty good, lots of options.

Answer (score 1):

In the animation panel flyout menu, choose the (somewhat misleading, imho) "Flatten Frames into Layers." That will give you a layer for each frame.

Export the layers using File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files.

Comment: It's been a while but eventually got around to looking into this. This doesn't do what I want. I already have all of the seperate frames in seperate files. I want them all in one big spritesheet file.

Comment: Ah, you want to IMport to a sprite sheet! Try this: http://spritetool.codeplex.com, which is free and has an entire tutorial on the subject in addition to the utility to create the sprite sheet. If that doesn't work, Google "sprite sheet creator" and pick one. There are lots out there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1. `Image > Canvas Size` - Height (unchanged), Width 1600px (or however big you need)
2. Select `Move Tool (v)`
3. Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> to lock the y-axis and drag each layer sideways to create a sprite sheet.
4. `Layer > Merge Visible`
5. Save and enjoy

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions